# ''Do you have an account on the website or in the website?''

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

When asking someone what should I say?

> Do you have an account **on**  facebook? 
>  
>   Do you have an account **in** facebook?

I can simply ask- ''Do you have a facebook account?'' 
But I'm asking should I use **on** or **in** .

Comment: A Facebook account

Answer (score 1):

You have accounts ON websites. This is just a convention, just as having an account WITH a bank is.

By the way, it would be "Do you have **a** Facebook account?". "An" is used before words which start with a vowel.

Comment: Typing error...didn't double check :p

Answer (score 0):

> ‘Seemingly, however, this sort of thing seems to be acceptable **on**
>    websites and in emails.’

The example is from Oxforddictionaries.com. The same preposition is used with "site" in the same meaning. Consider it as a surface just to memorize.